# Ignore previous rows in the UNION based on key

Tags: postgresql, union

I have a table with task delivery times, which is based on the task department (only), task category (only), or product task and category. These rules can be applied directly to a customer, a group of customers or to all customers.

Example:

- Customer 01 + Departament: Design + Category: Create Logo = 24 hours
- Customer 01 + Departament: Design + Any Category = 48 hours All
- Customers + Departament: Design + Any Category = 72 hours All
- Customers + Any Category + Category: Create Logo = 48 hours

This table has the structure below:

```
|rule_id|customer_id|departament_id|category_id|deadline|
```

SQL to create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_customer (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.test_departament (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.test_category (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.test_task (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_id INTEGER,
    departament_id INTEGER,
    category_id INTEGER,
    description varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE public.test_time_rule (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    customer_id INTEGER,
    departament_id INTEGER,
    category_id INTEGER,
    time_deadline INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO public.test_customer (id, name) VALUES(1, 'Customer with Rule');
INSERT INTO public.test_customer (id, name) VALUES(2, 'Customer without Rule');

INSERT INTO public.test_departament (id, name) VALUES(1, 'Front-End');
INSERT INTO public.test_departament (id, name) VALUES(2, 'Back-End');
INSERT INTO public.test_departament (id, name) VALUES(3, 'DBA');

INSERT INTO public.test_departament (id, name) VALUES(1, 'Design');
INSERT INTO public.test_departament (id, name) VALUES(2, 'Create HTML Pages');
INSERT INTO public.test_departament (id, name) VALUES(3, 'Create Tables');
INSERT INTO public.test_departament (id, name) VALUES(4, 'Fix Bugs');

INSERT INTO public.test_task (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, description) VALUES(1, 1, 1, 1, 'Create New Form Design');
INSERT INTO public.test_task (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, description) VALUES(2, 1, 2, 4, 'Fix Bug on Customer Table');
INSERT INTO public.test_task (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, description) VALUES(2, 1, 3, 3, 'Create City Table');
INSERT INTO public.test_task (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, description) VALUES(3, 2, 1, 1, 'Create New Form Design');
INSERT INTO public.test_task (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, description) VALUES(4, 2, 3, 3, 'Create City Table');

INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 20); --All Customers
INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(2, NULL, 1, NULL, 30); --All Customers + Departament
INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(3, NULL, NULL, 1, 40); --All Customers + Category
INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(4, NULL, 3, 3, 50); --All Customers + Departament + Category

INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(5, 1, NULL, NULL, 20); --Customers With Rule
INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(6, 1, 1, NULL, 30); --Customers + Departament
INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(7, 1, NULL, 1, 40); --Customers + Category
INSERT INTO public.test_time_rule (id, customer_id, departament_id, category_id, time_deadline) VALUES(8, 1, 3, 3, 50); --Customers + Departament + Category
```

I am trying to create a `SELECT` that lists all the tasks and show which rule applies to it.
For this I am using application levels of the rule, which are:

1 - Rule with customer + department + category (defined customer ID)

2 - Rule with customer group + department + category (defined customer group ID)

3 - General rule (all customer) + department + category (without defined customer and customer group ID)

4 - Rule with customer + department

I have summarized the rules, but they reach up to 16 rules, and i created a view for each rule with the tasks that match its parameters.

Based on these rules I created a `SELECT` with several `UNION ALL` (performance reasons), but as the row can be repeated due to a previous select, I ended up adding `NOT EXISTS` conditions to prevent this problem.

Example:

```
 SELECT
    1 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NOT NULL
    AND tt.customer_id = ttr.customer_id
    AND tt.departament_id = ttr.departament_id
    AND tt.category_id = ttr.category_id
UNION
SELECT
    2 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NOT NULL
    AND tt.departament_id = ttr.departament_id
    AND tt.category_id = ttr.category_id
UNION
SELECT
    3 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NULL
    AND tt.customer_id = ttr.customer_id
    AND tt.departament_id = ttr.departament_id
UNION
SELECT
    4 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NULL
    AND tt.departament_id = ttr.departament_id
UNION
SELECT
    5 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NOT NULL
    AND tt.customer_id = ttr.customer_id
    AND tt.category_id = ttr.category_id
UNION
SELECT
    6 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NOT NULL
    AND tt.category_id = ttr.category_id
UNION
SELECT
    7 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NULL
    AND tt.customer_id = ttr.customer_id
UNION
SELECT
    8 as level,
    ttr.id as rule_id,
    ttr.customer_id as rule_customer_id,
    tt.customer_id as task_customer_id,
    ttr.departament_id as rule_departament_id,
    tt.departament_id as task_departament_id,
    ttr.category_id as rule_category_id,
    tt.category_id as task_category_id,
    tt.id as task_id,
    tt.description as task_description,
    ttr.time_deadline
FROM
    test_time_rule ttr,
    test_task tt
WHERE
    ttr.customer_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.departament_id IS NULL
    AND ttr.category_id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    level;
```

As you may have noticed at each level that it enters, all the previous views are added, which generates a large and slow SQL.

My common sense tells me that this is not the best way to make this consultation.

I considered something that ignores a row based on the task id already displayed in a previous union.
Is there a better way to create this SELECT?

Note: I cannot add the rule ID used in the task, as this rule can be changed, deleted or even added in the future to a rule that best matches the task.

Comment: Your structure is not clear. Please add it as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, and show desired output for this data strictly with explanations referred to definite values (use non-divisible values for ambiguity absence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `task_id` to be unique, how about something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (task_id)
       *
FROM (SELECT /* first query */
      UNION ALL
      SELECT /* second query */
      ...) AS q
ORDER BY task_id, /* other criteria */
```

That will return the first row for each `task_id` in the specified ordering.

Comment: I tried using `UNION`, but since a task can match two rules, it ends up doubling the row that returns the task ID.
Eg .: It can match the rule that is intended for a client that sets the deadline for all his tasks, regardless of the department and category. It also match a general rule for all clients for a specific department. So I ended up using `NOT EXISTS` in the search conditions.

Comment: So the rows you want to eliminate are not exact duplicates, right? Please edit the question and tell us what makes rows duplicates.

Comment: I edited the question, adding the structure of the tables, sample data and the query model used that returns the duplicate data.

Comment: Perhaps I understood this time.

Comment: Using it that way he actually removed the duplicates, but did not bring them based on the rule that most closely matches. For example, for task id 1 it returned rule 3, but in fact it is rule 8 that has more items that correspond to the task (customer + department + category) (level 1, The lower the level, the greater the compatibility of the rule and task.).

Comment: I think I managed to get the results I wanted.
I added the main query within a subquery and this subquery ordered by task_id ASC and level ASC.

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (task_id)
       *
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT /* first query */
      UNION ALL
      SELECT /* second query */
      ...) x ORDER BY task_id ASC, level ASC) AS q
ORDER BY task_id, /* other criteria */`

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: That's what I meant by "other criteria". The `ORDER BY` must be in the outer query.

Comment: Your query saved my week. Thanks a lot for the help.